# How to count the number of unique values per group over the last n days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the pandas dataframe below:

| groupId | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | A |
| 1 | 2023-01-05 | B |
| 1 | 2023-01-17 | C |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 | A |
| 2 | 2023-01-20 | B |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 | A |
| 3 | 2023-01-10 | B |
| 3 | 2023-01-12 | C |

I would like to do a groupby and count the number of unique values for each `groupId` but only looking at the last n=14 days, relatively to the `date` of the row.

What I would like as a result is something like this:

| groupId | date | value | newColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | A | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-01-05 | B | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-01-17 | C | 2 |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 | A | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-01-20 | B | 1 |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 | A | 1 |
| 3 | 2023-01-10 | B | 2 |
| 3 | 2023-01-12 | C | 3 |

I did try using a `groupby(...).rolling('14d').nunique()` and while the `rolling` function works on numeric fields to count and compute the mean, etc ... it doesn't work when used with `nunique` on string fields to count the number of unique string/object values.

You can use the code below to generate the dataframe.

```
pd.DataFrame(
{
 'groupId': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
 'date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-17', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-20', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-10', '2023-01-12'], #YYYY-MM-DD
 'value': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
 'newColumn': [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
}
```

)

Do you have an idea on how to solve this, even if not using the `rolling` function? That'd be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible solution, which does not use `rolling`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['new2'] = df.groupby('groupId')['date'].transform(
    lambda x: x.diff().dt.days.cumsum().le(14).mul(~x.duplicated()).cumsum()+1)
```

Output:

```
   groupId       date value  new2
0        1 2023-01-01     A     1
1        1 2023-01-05     B     2
2        1 2023-01-17     C     2
3        2 2023-01-01     A     1
4        2 2023-01-20     B     1
5        3 2023-01-01     A     1
6        3 2023-01-10     B     2
7        3 2023-01-12     C     3
```

Comment: Thanks PaulS! It does the job nicely! I'll accept this as answer as it solves the problem I had.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `nunique`, you can also use `count`:

```
>>> (df.groupby('groupId').rolling('14D', on='date')['value'].count()
       .astype(int).rename('newColumn').reset_index())

   groupId       date  newColumn
0        1 2023-01-01          1
1        1 2023-01-05          2
2        1 2023-01-17          2
3        2 2023-01-01          1
4        2 2023-01-20          1
5        3 2023-01-01          1
6        3 2023-01-10          2
7        3 2023-01-12          3
```

**Caveats**: it can be complicated to merge this output with your original dataframe except if (groupId, date) is a unique combination.

**Update**

If your index is numeric (or create a dummy column monotonic increasing), you can use this trick:

```
sr = (df.reset_index().groupby('groupId').rolling('14D', on='date')
        .agg({'value': 'count', 'index': 'max'}).astype(int)
        .set_index('index')['value'])
df['newColumn'] = sr
print(df)

# Output
   groupId       date value  newColumn
0        1 2023-01-01     A          1
1        1 2023-01-05     B          2
2        1 2023-01-17     C          2
3        2 2023-01-01     A          1
4        2 2023-01-20     B          1
5        3 2023-01-01     A          1
6        3 2023-01-10     B          2
7        3 2023-01-12     C          3
```

**Update 2**

You can use `pd.factorize` to convert `value` column as numeric column:

```
>>> (df.assign(value=pd.factorize(df['value'])[0])
       .groupby('groupId').rolling('14D', on='date')['value']
       .apply(lambda x: x.nunique())
       .astype(int).rename('newColumn').reset_index())

   groupId       date  newColumn
0        1 2023-01-01          1
1        1 2023-01-05          2
2        1 2023-01-17          2
3        2 2023-01-01          1
4        2 2023-01-20          1
5        3 2023-01-01          1
6        3 2023-01-10          2
7        3 2023-01-12          3
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I know that the `count` works but it will count values (rows), not unique/distinct values, which is what I was looking to accomplish with the `nunique` function. Unfortunately, `nunique` does not seem to handle strings when used on `RollingGroupby`.

Comment: @confused_pandas. I updated my answer with an another solution based on `pd.factorize`.

Comment: @Corralien: It seems that only your third solution works when there is duplicated (non unique) rows. Take, as an example, the same dataframe and replace row `2` by `[2 1 2023-01-05 B]`

Comment: I'm getting a `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate` with the 2nd update. I did try it earlier as it was mentioned on a similar problem. 
Appreciate your help Corralien!